# Binomial distribution

Tags: self-study, distributions, variance, binomial-distribution, mean

folks! The problems is

Suppose you can make free throws at a 70% rate.  Let X be the number of free throws you make in 20 tries.  Model this with a binomial distribution:

1)?= E[X]

2)?=Var[X]

3)?=P(X = 15)

4)?=P(X ≤ 12)

I'm assuming for the first problem I'll use E[X] = n*p; for the second one V[X] = np(1-p) but how about third and fourth problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E(X) = 20 \times 0.7 =14 \\ var(X) =20 \times 0.7 \times 0.3 =4.2 $

$$P(x\le 12) = P(X=1) + ...+ P(X=12) =$$

$$=\binom{20}{1} (0.7)^1 (0.3)^{20-1} +...+\binom{20}{12} (0.7)^{12} (0.3)^{20-12} =$$

$$=\sum_{X=1}^{12} \binom{20}{X} (0.7)^X (0.3)^{20-X}$$

$P(X=15) = \binom{20}{15} (0.7)^{15} (0.3)^{20-15} $

Comment: sorry for interrupting again, but for x<=12 do I have to put 1 instead of n? Thanks in advance!

Comment: for which n? i wrote the sum of each P(X=n)

Comment: For the third problem do I have to plug in numbers from 1 to 12 instead of n? If yes, is there any easier way to calculate them?